# How to implement Netlify Forms on Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I've been able to receive forms on another site using this same method, but for some reason I do not receive submissions on this site. Netlify dashboard says collecting from 1 form (with the correct name) and honeypot field is enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form name='contact' method='POST' className='contactForm' data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" action='/success' >
  <input type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="inquiry" />
  <input id='f1' type='text' name='name' required placeholder="name*"/>
  <input id='f6' type='email' name='address' required placeholder="email address*"/>
  <textarea id='f5' id='message' name='message' required placeholder="message*"></textarea>
  <button id='f8' type='submit' className='submitForm' name='submit'>submit!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your form's `name` attribute and the value of the hidden `form-name` field are the same. In your example, the value should be **contact**

```
<form name='contact' method='POST' className='contactForm' data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field" action='/success' >
  <input type="hidden" name="bot-field" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
  <input id='f1' type='text' name='name' required placeholder="name*"/>
  <input id='f6' type='email' name='address' required placeholder="email address*"/>
  <textarea id='f5' id='message' name='message' required placeholder="message*"></textarea>
  <button id='f8' type='submit' className='submitForm' name='submit'>submit!</button>
</form>
```